# Getting the physical path

Tags: c#

I have to fetch all the files from a folder and i am using the function GetFiles() like

```
string[] dirImages = Directory.GetFiles(strPathYearImages + intYear , "*.png");
```

where strPathYearImages="Images\Holiday\2010\"

but when i write the whole path like

```
string[] dirImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\IWP\Images\Holiday\"+ intYear , "*.png");
```

i get the required result.

How to solve this problem? I dont want to use the whole path.
Help me out.

Regards,
Jigar <3

Comment: Is it that you don't want to USE the whole path or you don't want to HARDCODE the whole path?  If the later, and if you are talking about a directory relative to the directory in which the assembly is executing, there are some methods that will return the path in which the assembly is executing that you could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey all, i got the answer to my question.
I just had to write

string[] dirImages = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strPathImages + intYear , "*.png");

Hope that it is helpful to all...

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) says:

> The path parameter is permitted to
>   specify relative or absolute path
>   information. **Relative path information
>   is interpreted as relative to the
>   current working directory**

So you would want to make sure the current working directory is set correctly before trying to use the relative paths (eg to E:\IWP):

[GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)

[SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Application.StartupPath` to get the location where the executable is running. From there you need to know where the images directory is relative to that directory. The only other option is the absolute path. How else would it know where to look?

You can also try using `System.IO.Path` methods to help - especially for combining path strings, plus it also gives you the location of special folders like My Documents, AppData, and the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because you are running it from VS inside. Your executable is in ProjectName\bin\Debug, therefore it looks for ProjectName\bin\Debug\Images, which obviously does not exists.

Comment: No it is not the case. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the first snippet tries to get the images under current path. So you could tell the images path relative to your current path.

Comment: Yes but how can i get the whole path? It is like the Images folder can be placed anywhere so i have to make the path dynamicaccording to the path where Images folder is placed.

Comment: You cannot determine the full path to something you do not know where it resides. So you have to search fist.